# I want to change the Android dark mode dynamically

Tags: android, android-darkmode

In my Android project currently under development, there are many Fragments in Activity.
And inside the Fragment, RecyclerView is used to show multiple Items to the user.

What I want is that when the user changes the dark mode or light mode in the status bar, the dark mode is applied without exiting the app.
What should I do?

Comment: Changing between dark and light modes does not exit the app. It will cause a configuration change for the foreground activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know how to call onConfigurationChanged() function. But what I want to know is, how do I know if the user set the mobile mode to dark mode or light mode?

Comment: "I know how to call onConfigurationChanged() function" -- you do not call that yourself. It gets called by the framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare So what I mean is that it at least knows how to call onConfiguration() (when the user changes something in the config). My question is, how can I find the mode set by the user in the parameter config in onConfiguration()? How can I know the values ​​for the dark mode and light mode set by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `Configuration`, you can find out whether the device is in dark mode by examining `uiMode`:

```kotlin
val currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
when (currentNightMode) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {} // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {} // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
}
```

(source code from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#config-changes))

You can get a `Configuration`:

- At the point of a configuration change, by opting out of `uiMode` in the manifest and overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` in your activity, or
- At any point by calling `getResources().getConfiguration()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Finally, I wonder if it is possible to change the theme of a fragment without exiting the fragment. When the user freely changes the dark and light modes in the mode change in the status bar, can the running app dynamically apply the mode? How?